# Android AVD With HAXM Takes 1 Minute to Load APK Every Time, Normal?

Tags: android, performance, installation, emulation, android-virtual-device

Man, I'm getting frustrated.

I just re-installed the Android ADT bundle because my AVD speeds were horrible, we're talking 2-3 minutes to load an AVD with a new APK, crazy. After the re-install, I found HAXM.

Installing HAXM has made a HUGE difference, however, I'm finding that the build, upload and install of my app through Eclipse and the AVD is still taking 1 minute! This is terribly frustrating as I like to make subtle changes, test, and then continue. Imagine a minute wait between each build, ugh...

Anyway, is this normal? If so, how do you cope with it, are there any tricks as far as .ini settings etc? I really appreciate it, I'd love to have sub 20 second load times, I think that is reasonable as my actual phone loads in less than 5 seconds.

Please let me know, thanks!

EDIT: Ok, it appears that this is a disk utilization issue! Sometimes, when the emulator is installing the APK disk read/write hits 100% capacity, it's like the emulator is writing or reading out of control, yet only 0.1 mb/s is being written... Very strange..

Comment: SOLVED - If you find this is your problem, increase your HAXM RAM usage to 3 GB (do this through re-installing HAXM), then, increase all of your AVD's RAM to 1024 with 64 VMHeap. Installations and runs of the debugger are instant, I can't believe it!!!

Comment: UPDATE - Was solved, until a reboot. Now, I have 53 second load times on my APK installs from Eclipse to the AVD, crazy slow. I checked the HAXM RAM setting and it HAD reverted back to 2 GB, I increased it back to 3 GB, however, it took a reboot before the 1 second install times came back, what the heck?!

Comment: Hi, I installed HAXM in hopes that it would help with AVD performance, but other than launching the AVD a bit quicker, the UI still is way too slow to test any real applications. Is HAXM just to help launch the AVD or should it improve AVD responsiveness as well?

Comment: @Shijima it should do both. It should make the AVD load almost instantly, and the AVD should feel pretty close to Android speeds. I used to have a great experience with HAXM before Windows 8...

Answer (score 0):

You can use genymotion emulator. It works very fast compared to any emulator offered by eclipse or android studio. You can download it for free.

Comment: Geny is OK. I have a paid license, it crashes A LOT.

Comment: Android Studio 2.0 is in Beta stage. It will roll out soon. It appears, they have made it very fast, the compiler and emulator both.